# What is meant by "global smooth coordinates"?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

On p. 65 of John M. Lee's book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, we find the following as part of Exercise 3.17:

*Verify that $(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})$ are smooth coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^2$, where*

$$\tilde{x}=x; \;\;\tilde{y} = x^3+y.$$

What is meant by showing that these are global smooth coordinates? Are we just showing that $(x,y) \mapsto (x,x^3+y):\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a diffeomorphism?

Thanks folks

Comment: Could be that $\tilde{y} = x^3 + y$ was intended.

Comment: You are right! It was my transcription mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Global coordinates on a manifold $M$ are coordinates that are globally defined, and yield a homeomorphism (diffeomorphism in the case of differentiable manifolds) between $M$ and an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ (where $d$ is the topological dimension of the manifold). In other words, local coordinates whose coordinate patch is the entire manifold.

Not to be confused with globally defined local coordinates, which are maps $\varphi\colon M \to \mathbb{R}^d$ such that every $m\in M$ has a neighbourhood $U$ such that the restriction $\varphi\lvert_U$ is a coordinate chart, like $z \mapsto e^z$ for $\mathbb{C}$ [of course, global coordinates are also globally defined local coordinates, but in general not vice versa].

So you need to check that $(x,y) \mapsto (\tilde{x},\tilde{y})$ is indeed a diffeomorphism (easy), and that the differential operators $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial\tilde{x}}$ are different (not quite as easy, but easy enough still).

Comment: Just came across this comment whil searching for "global coordinates on manifolds." Your "globally defined local coordinates" are just what I am looking for. Could you provide a reference?

Comment: Hm, I was convinced I came across it in the literature here and there, but so far I have found it only in my old notes of the lecture on several complex variables.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused by the definitions here. On the one hand, it seems natural to interpret "smooth global coordinates" as meaning "the map $(x,y) \mapsto (\bar x, \bar y)$ is a diffeomorphism"; but on the other hand, Lee defines a "smooth coordinate map" to be any chart contained in a smooth structure. This does not require the chart to be a diffeomorphism, it only requires that it is smoothly compatible with all other charts, which in this case is an empty condition (there is only one chart). Are these not two conflicting definitions?

Comment: @Andreas a "chart" is - or at least should be - by definition a diffeomorphism [homeomorphism if we're looking at topological manifolds, and not differentiable ones] between its domain and image. And a smooth structure is usually defined as a _maximal_ collection of mutually compatible charts, so for any non-empty manifold of positive dimension, a smooth structure contains a lot of coordinate charts.

Comment: You're right about the smooth structure being maximal and therefore containing more than one chart, I forgot about that. Thank you. However, I am still a bit confused: Lee's book only requires the charts to be homeomorphisms that are smoothly compatible with each other (i.e. the transition maps are diffeomorphisms), but each individual chart need not be a diffeomorphism. Maybe these are somehow equivalent definitions, or maybe I have misunderstood the book.

Comment: @Andreas Differentiability is defined in terms of the charts, $f\colon U \to N$, where $U$ is open in $M$, is differentiable/smooth if and only if for all charts belonging to the respective differentiable structures the map $\psi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is differentiable/smooth where defined. By the mutual compatibility of charts, one needs only check systems of charts covering $U$ resp. $f(U) \subset N$. If $f$ happens to be a chart, $N = \mathbb{R}^{\dim M}$, so we can take the identity for $\psi$, and for $\varphi$ we take $f$. Then _in the chosen charts_, the chart $f$ is the identity,

Comment: hence smooth. To see that $f$ is a diffeomorphism between its domain and image, we need to see that $f^{-1}$ is smooth. Now $f^{-1} \colon V \to U\subset M$ where $V$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\dim M}$, so we can take the identity chart for $\varphi$, and we can take $\psi = f$. Then $\psi \circ f^{-1}\circ \varphi^{-1} = f\circ f^{-1}\circ \operatorname{id}^{-1} = \operatorname{id}$, so $f^{-1}$ is smooth too. As both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are smooth, $f$ is a diffeomorphism.